# Change the year of 500+ photos in iPhoto

Tags: photos.app

For quite some time I had my camera configured with the wrong year. How can I change the year portion of the date of 500+ photos in my iPhotos library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In iPhoto '09 (or later, I believe)...

1. Select all the photos with incorrect dates
2. In the menu bar, select Photos -> Adjust Date and Time
3. Modify the date to reflect the change you want -- for example, to shift all the photos forward one year, increment just the year part of the date by 1
4. All the photos will be time-shifted by the relative change you specified